# In Firestore RealTime DB (NoSQL), if I were to update a "subtree" with a "set" command, will it overlay the existing document?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I'm curious about the change detection aspect of Firestore Realtime.   If I issue a "set" command, will it flag the entire subtree as being "changed" or just the actual fields that did change?

Answer (score 0):

What happens doesn't depend on the command fired, but on the path to the data that is changed and the path that is listened to.

Say you have a data structure like this:

```
"users": {
  "user1": { ... },
  "user2": { ... },
  "user3": { ... },
}
```

If you write (create, update, or delete) to `/users/user1`, then any listener on the path `/users/user1/*` will be notified of that write. But listeners on `/users/user2`, `/users/user3`, or on any other top-level node will not be notified, as there we no changes to the data they listen to.

Similarly, if you create a new top-level node `messages`, then any listener on the path `/messages` or lower will be notified - but listeners on `/users` or below, or or on any other path in the database won't be notified.

The only time a listener will be notified of **all** changes is when it listens on the root of the database, as a change anywhere in the database affect the data that this listener observes.

Comment: So if user2 was the only object changed during a 'dispatch(users)'......only subtrees that include user2 will fire when listened to?

Comment: Not sure what `dispatch(users)` does there, as it's not a Firebase API call. But if you only modify `/users/user2`, then only listeners on paths that include that node will be notified indeed. --- If this isn't clear yet, I recommend creating an example in code and sharing that. In most cases I find the API quite self-explanatory once you see it in action, and if it doesn't - we can focus on that specific case.